# How to draw on JPanel on fixed position?

Tags: java, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have JPanel wrapped in JScrollPane and I want the rectangle to be drawn always on the same position = moving with scrollbars wont affect the visibility of the rectangle.

I tried following code:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(50, (int)getVisibleRect().getY(), 20 , 20);
    }
```

but it only repaints the rectangle when size of whole JPanel is changed.

Comment: Post a SSCCE: http://sscce.org, with your question so we can see the exact problem. For example is the problem that you didn't include a super.paintComponent() in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, `JScrollPane` will try to minimise the amount of redrawing done scrolling, so it wont always cause your component to be updated.

The standard technique is to use a `JLayeredPane`. Add you `JScrollPane` to a lower layer, and a non-opaque glass panel component above it. See [How to Use a Layered Pane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) in the Swing tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollPanePaint extends JFrame
{
    public ScrollPanePaint()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque( false );
        panel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(400, 400) );

        JViewport viewport = new JViewport()
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
                g.drawArc( 100, 100, 80, 80, 0, 360);
            }
        };

        viewport.setView( panel );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewport( viewport );
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 300) );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ScrollPanePaint();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setLocation` method. Visit [setLocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29) for more info.