# Create translucent and blurred components in java

Tags: java, blur, effects, translucentdecor

I need to create a panel which is partially transparent and which blurs what appears behind the panel. Such as the title bar in widows 7. Help me if someone knows how to do this very simply

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562225/java-set-opacity-in-jpanel

Comment: Thank you. But I knew how to make a component transparent. The exact problem I had was how make blur what appears behind the panel.

Comment: What happens if you set alpha=0.5?

Comment: setting alpha channel to 0.5 makes the component transparent. I need it to be blurred what appears behind.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer for you, but if you update your question with what you've tried, the results you're getting and the desired results, it will help people give you more relevant answers. It will also bump the question so more people will see it.