# Creating scalable checkered margin in java swing

Tags: java, swing, graph, jpanel, paint

I need to write programm which must drawing graphs.. I use java with swing (if you think that swing it is not good decigion please offer other tools) .. And my teacher say that I must drawing graphs on checkered margin and I don't know what use in this situation.. If someone do something like this please help me.. How make this checkered margin (and my teacher say to me that this checkered margin must be scalable)

**UPDATE**

Oh I forget to say that I mast drawing graph by myself (set 2 dots and then my function must draw line between this dots)

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel ... use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for your graphs. Unless your assignment does not allow that

Comment: More on `JFreeChart` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info). For specific help, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, [`MyPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518047/230513) draws a gray checkerboard in its background; [`SineTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9373195/230513) shows how to plot using cartesian coordinates.