# setting JLabel transparency

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

You may see this as a duplicate question but please here me out.

I have a JLabel with an image. This JLabel has a mouse listener binded to some function. 
Is there any way to make the JLabel disappear (or technically, transparent) in order for the mouse listener function to be preserved?

I know I can set a transparent image as an icon to the JLabel, but I'm wondering if there's some kind of "toggle" function out there.

Comment: Why must "the `JLabel` disappear … in order for the mouse listener [to] function?"

Comment: Lets say I have a border that I use to take care of resizing the window. I then want to make this border disappear/appear whenever I want, but obviously preserving its resizing function for both options. I think this is a good example.

Comment: @nivde92: Can you tell me which parts are you having trouble understanding? Let's say I have a button. However I want to hide this button but it can still be clicked (if the user knows exactly where it is). Something like this but translated to JLabels.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the scenario you describe.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is quite is hard to understand. I'll try making an sscce after I get home.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `yourLabel.setVisible(false);` is not the same as dispose the frame; however, would you extend your question a little bit more or make it clearer?(I'm having a hard time trying to understand what do you want to do)

Comment: See my reply on your comment. Also `setVisible(false)` seems to be removing the function also. This is probably because of how Mouse Listeners work.

Comment: hmmm there's a method called setOpaque(boolean), however some swing elements doesn't work whit these, because they inherit they behavior from the look and feel that you are using, I've used Jpanels in order to make them "disapear" but all the listener still work, why you don't try to use this element instead?

Comment: More on _opacity_ v. _transparency_ [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3518047/230513).