# Drawing a static image over the viewport of a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to draw a red square over a JScrollPane. The code I have below does an okay job of this, but sometimes when I scroll the viewport too fast, the red square jumps up or down.

[image]

This struck me as odd since the JScrollPane itself is stationary, so I assumed Swing would not try to move around the components painted within it. I'm guessing that what's actually happening is that the the red square gets associated with viewport, which display graphics that do move.

Anyway, how do I prevent the red square from jumping around and successfully draw a red square over the list? Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach altogether.

```
package components;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DialogWithScrollPane extends JFrame {

  public DialogWithScrollPane() {
    super();

    setResizable(false);
    Container pane = getContentPane();

    Vector<Object> listOfStuff = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      listOfStuff.add(Integer.toString(i));
    }

    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane() {

      public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("JScrollPane.paint() called.");
        super.paint(g);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 200);
      }
    };
    JList list = new JList(listOfStuff) {
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("JList.paint() called.");
        super.paint(g);

        // Well, I could do this...
            //
        // scrollPane.repaint();
        //
        // ...and it would solve the problem, but it would also result in an
        // infinite recursion since JScrollPane.paint() would call this
        // function again.
      }
    };

    // Repaint the JScrollPane any time the viewport is moved or an item in the
    // list is selected.
    scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        scrollPane.repaint();
      }
    });
    list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        scrollPane.repaint();
      }
    });

    scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

    pane.add(scrollPane);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(500, 250);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        new DialogWithScrollPane();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution might be too robust for this, but you could try drawing on the `Glass Pane`. For instance - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609888/drawing-between-2-images-in-1-jpanel/6610064#6610064 But I could be wrong and this solution may not be applicable.

Comment: @masson: please see edit to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JScrollPane should be painting *behind* the JViewport which should be painting *behind* the list. I'm guessing that this is only working because you're overriding paint and not paintComponent and calling repaint on the JScrollPane all the time so that it paints itself again after its components are painted.

Perhaps you want to use a JLayeredPane and have it hold the JScrollPane, and paint on it.

edit: or the glasspane as I now see that mre suggests, but I'm afraid if you do that, and set the glasspane visible, you'll lose the ability to interact with the underlying scrollpane.

**Edit 2**
For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DialogWithScrollPane2 extends JFrame {

   public DialogWithScrollPane2() {
      super();

      //setResizable(false);
      final JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();

      Vector<Object> listOfStuff = new Vector<Object>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         listOfStuff.add(Integer.toString(i));
      }

      final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      JList list = new JList(listOfStuff);

      scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

      final JPanel blueRectPanel = new JPanel() {
         @Override
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 200);
         }
      };
      blueRectPanel.setOpaque(false);

      final JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
      layeredPane.add(scrollPane, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
      layeredPane.add(blueRectPanel, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

      layeredPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

         private void resizeLayers() {
            final JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
            scrollPane.setBounds(layeredPane.getBounds());
            blueRectPanel.setBounds(viewport.getBounds());
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  blueRectPanel.setBounds(viewport.getBounds());
               }
            });
         }

         @Override
         public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            resizeLayers();
         }

         @Override
         public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            resizeLayers();
         }
      });

      pane.add(layeredPane);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setLocation(500, 250);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new DialogWithScrollPane2();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that your edit is true. In that example, I do intentionally block all input events and the `Glass Pane` does intercept them, but I'm not sure if it blocks them entirely by default. So, the ability to interact with the underlying scollpane may still be there, but I haven't tested this! :D

Comment: It would be worth testing. :D

Comment: @masson see rellevant post about painting whatever on JViewPort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006522/how-to-add-background-image-in-jtable-when-printing/7006684#7006684 and see links by trashgod +1

Comment: @mKorbel: Please explain "(isn't your form Old.Forums.Sun"?

Comment: this nice example I have under your little bit E.... encrypted name from forums.sun.com aren't you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't know about JLayeredPane, and it makes a lot more sense in this case.

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes Encephalopathic I was and encephalopathic I am.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eels then my big enless thanks to your very kind help (on this old.good.forum)