# How to put a component on top of others?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlayeredpane, jviewport

I have a `JScrollPanel` that includes a big panel which it's self includes 3 inner panels. i want to put a panel (for example) in a special place so that always could be seen, I mean the user can scroll to anywhere wants but that panel always is in top of the other components and doesn't move. I tried to do that via `JLayeredPane` but I couldn't. how may I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629892/230513), but `OverlayLayout`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437388/230513), may be of interest. It's not included in the conventional [gallery](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

[image: OverlayLayout]

Also consider this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097538/230513) that paints on the scroll pane's `JViewport`.

[image: viewport]

Answer (score 5):

You could use

- The [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#glasspane)
- [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)

To overlay content on top of the other components on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just put the content that you don't want to move in a separate JPanel that isn't the scrolling panel? I don't see any reason to include it in the scrolling panel if you don't want it to scroll.

So have one big panel (call it bigPanel or something) that doesn't scroll. Then have the panel that you don't want to scroll in bigPanel. Then also put the scrolling panel in bigPanel as well.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: the reason which causes I want to put that panel on top of others, is the function which that panel has, that is going to be a notification bar that sometimes appears on top of the other things and after a while disappears. in other words the reason of why i want that on top of others not beside them refers to the design of my program GUI...

Comment: Do you actually want it to cover up the content of the other panels, or do you just want it to appear above them and then disappear? And by above I mean on the y axis, not the z axis.