# java swing for fixed panel like in AJAX AlwaysVisibleControl panel

Tags: java, swing

How to create an fixed panel on another panel, like in Google Map Zoom Panel which has zoom functionalities.

Any guidence is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to overlaying panel ontop of the other?

Comment: yes i wan to overlay on other panel,second panel can be scrolled,zoom panel should be fixed....

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: More ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14677267/230513).